# Creating a function that counts in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, function

so im trying to create my 1st simple function in mysql that counts the number of rows in 3 tables and returns the sum of the 3 counts. I figured this would be simple, but apparently not as i am getting an error everytime i try to create it. Im not sure why since it looks to me as i have declared everything correctly and used the right syntax where needed. But i still dont see why i am getting this error. Any ideas?

My function

```
mysql> create function Size()
    -> returns int
    -> deterministic 
    -> begin
    -> declare size int;
    -> set size = select count(r.name) + count(s.name) + count(j.name) as Total from ArmyRegiment r, ArmySpecRegiment s, ArmyJTF j, ArmySpecRegiment s, ArmyJTF j;
    -> return size;
    -> end//
```

The error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select count(r.name) + count(s.name) + count(j.name) as Total from ArmyRegiment' at line 1
```

Also, i get this error as soon as i type in end // before i can do delimiter ; . Anyways, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `return int(100000)` should be `returns int(100000)`. Notice that it's `RETURNS`. Moreover, I think you can just say `returns int`.

Again, I think with your `SET` statement; you are trying to add up the `count()` result probably

```
set size = select count(r.name) + count(s.name) + count(j.name) 
from ArmyRegiment r, ArmySpecRegiment s, ArmyJTF j;
```

(OR)

```
declare size int;
set size = 0;
select count(name) into size from ArmyRegiment;
select size + count(name) into size from ArmySpecRegiment;
select size + count(name) into size from ArmyJTF;
```

(OR)

```
select count(r.name) + count(s.name) + count(j.name) INTO size
from ArmyRegiment r, ArmySpecRegiment s, ArmyJTF j;
```

Comment: oh, im so used to C++ return, and  if i do int, whats the default size? the database can be huge so thats why it set to 100000. After editing it, im still getting the error: this time its from the select sum.. ArmyRegiment r

Comment: @ShadowViper, default? If you just say `INT` .. it can accommodate 2^32 I believe (max value `2147483647`).

Comment: oh ok thanks, but im still getting an error, i modified the question above with the fix and the error

Comment: didnt see that u edited it, but unfortunately, that didnt work, same error

Comment: @ShadowViper, I don't think you really checked my edited answer. See now.

Comment: @ShadowViper, just say `select dbo.Size();` Also a suggestion, consider reading MySQL documentation or a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SUM across multiple columns as you are doing
If you want those individual counts added up you need to add them yourself

```
select count(r.name) + count(s.name) + count(j.name) as summed from ArmyRegiment r, ArmySpecRegiment s, ArmyJTF j;
```

However I doubt that is the result that you actually want as you appear to be doing a full outer join of the three tables so you will get the result of countR * countS * countJ

Comment: In what way does it not "work" are you sill getting a syntax error or is the result not what you expected?

Comment: yup, still getting the error, see the question, i edited it with the new syntax and error

Comment: You updated the syntax, but not the error as that is still showing the original error.  Plus if you are making changes from the original code it is best to leave the original code in the question and add a EDIT section at the bottom to show what you have changed, otherwise answers based on the original question don't make sense anymore.